# Add / Remove user from role by ID [DISCORD.JS]

Tags: discord.js

Hey today I'd like give and remove roles from a user by their ID

First try:

```js
const user = '5454654687868768'
const role = '451079228381724672'

user.roles.remove(role)
```

Second Try:

```js
const user = '5454654687868768'
const role = '451079228381724672'

user.removeRole(role)
```

Neither one of these methods seems to work, however.

Comment: Have you tried reading any of the [Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) or the [Guide](https://discordjs.guide/)? [Discord.js Guide - How do I add a role to a guild member?](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/common-questions.html#how-do-i-add-a-role-to-a-guild-member)

Comment: Yeah but the documentation take "message mention members" and no ID

Comment: Hum i see. Thank you.

Comment: Even if the page I linked doesn't answer your question exactly, reading the guide, in general, will lead you to a greater understanding of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const user = '5454654687868768'
const role = '451079228381724672'
```

These are just numbers which happen to be the id of your user and role object. They are nothing on their own and you can't call any Discordjs methods on them. To get the user and role object you will first have to get them using their respective ID.

Let's assume you want to add a role when someone joins the server, you can do the same thing in any type of event but we will use guildMemberAdd event for example:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const memberID = '5454654687868768';   // you want to add/remove roles. Only members have roles not users. So, that's why I named the variable memberID for keeping it clear.
    const roleID = '451079228381724672';

    const guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('guild-ID');   // copy the id of the server your bot is in and paste it in place of guild-ID.
    const role = guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);  // here we are getting the role object using the id of that role.
    const member = await guild.members.fetch(memberID); // here we are getting the member object using the id of that member. This is the member we will add the role to.
    member.roles.add(role);   // here we just added the role to the member we got.
}
```

See these methods are only working because they are real discordjs objects and not some numbers like you were trying to do. Also the async/await thing is there because we need to wait for the bot to get the member object from the API before we can add role to it.

Answer (score -1):

Your first try was actually not that far off. The only problem is that `roles.remove()` is a [`guildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/GuildMember) function.

So first we need to define the member.

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get("member ID here");
```

Now we can remove or add a role. [Source](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/GuildMemberRoleManager)

```
member.roles.remove("role ID here");
```